# where to put files not cloned by git in a repo?

Tags: android, rom, android-rom

problem: downloading android sourcecode via

```
repo init --depth=1 -u https://github.com/crdroidandroid/android -b 5.1.1

repo sync -c
```

I get the error:

```
error: Cannot checkout crdroidandroid/android_system_core: ManifestInvalidRevisionError: revision 5.1.1 in crdroidandroid/android_system_core not found
```

I have the files as they were moved to an old branch:

https://github.com/crdroidandroid/android_system_core_old/tree/5.1.1

where do I put the files I downloaded from the above url... do they go in the /WORKSPACE/system/core folder?

also, where do I place the device tree, vendor and kernel repo files to let me compile the rom?

I have put the files I downloaded from the archived system core directory into the aformentioned folder but still need to clone my device's vendor, tree and kernel to one of the directories in the cloned repo... does anyone know where?